# android - completely clearing memory used by jni

Tags: android, memory, java-native-interface

I am creating an app that processes very large images on the jni side. And by very large images I mean that nearly all of the devices available RAM gets allocated into a few large blocks. The problem is that after allocating and releasing all of this memory, the same amount is no longer available.

Now, your first thought is probably that there is obviously a memory leak here! Well, there doesn't seem to be. I analysed my memory usage using

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo (app package)
```

These are my results:
Before processing:

```
                 Pss  Private  Private  Swapped     Heap     Heap     Heap
               Total    Dirty    Clean    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free
              ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
Native Heap    19736    19712       12     1268    36864    26663    10200
Dalvik Heap    15201    15176        0     3308    32992    16694    16298
```

During:

```
                 Pss  Private  Private  Swapped     Heap     Heap     Heap
               Total    Dirty    Clean    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free
              ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
Native Heap   889826   889804        8     1252   929792   914480    15311
Dalvik Heap    16769    16744        0     3308    33678    18541    15137
```

After:

```
                 Pss  Private  Private  Swapped     Heap     Heap     Heap
               Total    Dirty    Clean    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free
              ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
Native Heap    22234    22212        8     1252    45056    28468    16587
Dalvik Heap    16461    16436        0     3308    33871    17573    16298
```

Before and after aren't quite the same, but I also moved between activities in the mean time so there is noise.

It may also be the case that after processing data once, there is no longer a *continuous* block of memory available, but I still don't know how to avoid it.

I could possibly use a service in a separate process to do the jni stuff and kill the process afterwards, but I haven't tested this out so it might not work. Restarting the app and recreating the entire backstack seems to do the trick, though that might be quite hard to make completely stable, it will make things slower and I really don't want to do that.

Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: i am having a very similar issue, tann36 how did you solve yours?

Comment: @petyr I've answered my question now

Comment: thank you @tann36, i have already tried that solution without any improvement though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the issue was that the released memory apparently had to be garbage collected.

While using using the meminfo call seemed to imply that all memory was released, the call itself triggered garbage collecting. After my processing had finished but before calling meminfo, the memory was not available.

I managed to get everything working alright by calling `System.gc()`. I know it's not recommended and is said to only be a suggestion to the system, but it genuinely seemed to fix the issue.